# How to pass an EL function call to composite attribute?

Tags: javascript, function, jsf, el, composite-component

I have a composite with a button and I want to be able to pass a oncomplete String to that button.

```
<composite:attribute name="oncomplete"/>

<h:commandButton oncomplete="#{cc.attrs.oncomplete}"/>
```

Now I want to pass an EL function call which resolves a Javascript Object into this oncomplete field.

```
<comp:composite oncomplete="#{p:widgetVar('dlgUserAdd')}.hide();">

#{p:widgetVar('dlgUserAdd')} //returns a Javascript Object.
```

But this leads to an exception:

```
com.sun.el.lang.FunctionMapperImpl java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.el.lang.FunctionMapperImpl
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:959)
at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1430)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
```

This here works, but is not what I want to do:

```
<comp:composite oncomplete="dlgUserAdd.hide();">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hideWidget(widget){
    widget.hide();
  }
</script>

<comp:composite oncomplete="hideWidget(#{p:widgetVar('dlgUserAdd')})" />
```

Comment: This seems pretty ugly. The composite implementing site needs to know this function even it is not visible to it, or both the composite and the implementing site need to know it! Anyone else has an Idea?